# Can you denote a family $F: N → P(R)$ such that $F(n) = R\space, ∀n ∈ N$ in a set builder notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I don't fully understand the meaning of the following underlined explanation. Can you denote $F: N → P(R)$ such that $F(n) = R\space, ∀n ∈ N$ in a set builder notation?

> **Definition**
>   A family of sets is a function $F$ from an index set $I$ to some range set. Intuitively we consider {$F(i): i \in I$} to be the family of sets.
>
> It should be noted that a family is distinct from a set of sets, since a set may be repeated in a family, but can count only once as an element of a set. 
>   $\underline {\text{For example, the function}\space F\space \text{from}\space N\space to \space P(R),\space \text{such that} F(n) = R}$ $\underline {\space \text{for every} \space n\in N,\text{is a family, but} \{F(n): n\in N\}}$ $\underline {\text{as a set has precisely one element}}$.
>   Source: Numbers, Sets and Axioms: The Apparatus of Mathematics, A. G. Hamilton, p.132

Answer (score 1):

$F = \{ (n,\mathbb R) \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$ is a set (or family) of infinite size. But $\{F(n) \mid n \in \mathbb N \} = \{ \mathbb R \}$ has only a single element. The author probably provided this simple example to allow his reader to reflect on the definition of family.